# FASt Search Certificate Renewal

Tags: sharepoint-server, fast-search

We've renewed our FASTSearchCert certificate and content crawling is operational, however, we're noticing that our "FAST Search Query" SSA is struggling.

When we renewed our certificate we had to run:

```
.\SecureFASTSearchConnector.ps1 -ssaName "name of your content SSA" -username "domain\username"
```

But we only ran this for our content crawler SSA ("FAST Search Connector" in our enviornment).

We also have a Query SSA (named "FAST Search Query") and we wondered whether we need to run the `SecureFASTSearchConnector.ps1` script for this SSA, also?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps per TechNet on all FAST servers: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/fast-search-server-2010/ff381244(v=office.14)#replacing-the-default-self-signed-certificate. The securefastconnector script is to be run on each server with a crawl component.

Comment: we've already done this on all the servers related to our search infrastructure. We identified that the problem was related to some oo the crawl components. we've spent weeks on this... So far, things seem to be looking like they're working. We, essentially, rebuilt the SSA by creating new components within the SSA and seeing if the commponents stayed "Online" and stable.